# Assigning IP address in IP Header in C

Tags: c, sockets, ip-address

I am implementing a chat room application using raw sockets in C for my college project. I have a problem with assigning ip addresses.

packet is received from the socket. I am parsing it as shown. Now how to assign ip address.

I would rather like to do it in the way shown (means using rcv_ip as char),if possible. So before giving suggestion for using **struct in_addr** , help me with this. Because I have tried other methods which is further generating other confusions to me.

```
main()
{
char *rcv_ip;
char *packet;
int len;
struct iphdr ip_header;
rcv_ip=ParseIPHeader(packet,len);
printf("\n %s ",rcv_ip);  //printing some junk
printf("\n %s ",inet_addr(rcv_ip));  //giving seg fault
printf("\n %s",inet_ntoa(*((struct in_addr*)ip_header->daddr)));   //printing correct ip

ip_header CreateIPHeader(rcv_ip+5,rcv_ip);
}
```

Now ParseIPHeader function.

```
char *ParseIPHeader(packet,len)
{
     struct iphdr *ip_header;
     struct ethhdr *eth_header;
     char *ret_ip;

     ip_header=(struct iphdr *)(packet+sizeof(struct ethhdr));
     ret_ip=malloc(10);
     memset(ret_ip,0,10);
     memcpy(ret_ip,&(ip_header->daddr),sizeof(ip_header->daddr));
     memcpy(ret_ip+5,&(ip_header->saddr),4);

     return ret_ip;
}

struct iphdr *CreateIPHeader(char *src_ip,char *dst_ip)
{
    struct iphdr *ip_header;
ip_header=malloc(sizeof(struct iphdr));
    //main part. How to do this??
    ip_header->saddr = inet_addr(src_ip);  //please correct it.
ip_header->daddr = inet_addr(dst_ip);


return(ip_header);
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to expect that IP addresses are strings, since you try printing one with `printf()` and the `%s` format specifier. This is incorrect; IP addresses are binary in the header.

This means that an IPv4 address uses only 32 bits, while the textual representation might use at most 3+1+3+1+3+1+3 = 15 characters (plus the terminator, so 16).

Read up on more IP fundamentals.

Comment: yeah.. Thanks. That means I must use some struct containing ipaddress. would **struct in_addr**  be ok ?? I think I need two objects of this struct and then assign source and destination IPs to them. but how would I return both the IPs from **CreateIPHeader**  function ??